# Param returns nil value when passing from form_for using patch method

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm implementing a voting system where when the course is already upvoted/downvoted, clicking downvote/upvote will switch to that vote respectively and clicking again will delete that vote (similar to Reddit).
While voting and destroying vote perform correctly, I'm having trouble trying to update the vote with form_for and patch method, where the value of the vote_type returns nil

My Votes_Controller

```rb
class VotesController < ApplicationController
     def create
       @vote = Vote.new(secure_params)

       @vote.course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
       if @vote.save
           respond_to do |format|
                   format.html { redirect_to :courses }
                   format.js
         end
     end



    def update
          vote = Vote.find_by(user: current_user)

          vote.update_attribute(:vote_type, update_vote_params)
          redirect_to :courses
    end   

    def destroy
          vote = Vote.find_by(user: current_user)
          vote.destroy
          redirect_to :courses, :notice => 'Unvoted!'
    end   

    private
       def secure_params
          params.require(:vote).permit( :user_id, :vote_type )
       end

       def update_vote_params
          params.require(:vote).permit(:vote_type)
       end
  end
```

My index.html.erb

```html
<% if  Vote.exists?(user: current_user) && Vote.find_by(user: current_user).vote_type.equal?(-1) %>

            <%= form_for course.votes.build, url: course_vote_path(course, Vote.find_by(user: current_user).id), method: :patch do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :vote_type, value: 1 %>
              <%= f.submit 'Upvote', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
            <% end %>

        <% elsif Vote.exists?(user: current_user) && Vote.find_by(user: current_user).vote_type.equal?(1) %>
            <%= form_for course.votes.build, url: course_vote_path(course, Vote.find_by(user: current_user).id), method: :delete do |f| %>
            <%= f.submit "Upvote", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <%= form_for course.votes.build, url: course_votes_path(course) do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :vote_type, value: 1 %>
              <%= f.submit 'Upvote', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

My routes.rb

```rb
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
     get 'vote/create'
     get 'vote/destroy'
     get 'courses/new'
     get 'users/new'
    resources :courses do
          resources :votes, only: [:create, :destroy, :update]
    end
    resources :users
 end
```

I expect the param to pass 1 for vote_type, however, the actual output is nil

Comment: I've had issues with hidden field to where I have to manually insert them into the params hash. `<%= hidden_field_tag 'vote[vote_type]', 1 %>` Would usually clear that up for me.

Comment: @MikeHeft Well that still doesn't work for me. This is so weird, I don't seem to miss anything, and the update method is called correctly. Only the param does not go through

Comment: Sorry, :(  Wish I was more help

Comment: In the `elsif` body, shouldn't it be "Downvote" instead of "Upvote". That won't fix it, but it's just a typo I think. And in that same `elsif`, aren't you missing the checkbox with value of `-1` ?, it should also update it, isn't it ?

Comment: @fanta what I'm trying to implement is basically similar to reddit voting system. Once you upvote/downvote, clicking upvote/downvote again will destroy that vote (unvote), and clicking the opposite vote will make your vote to switch to that vote instead

Comment: Ahh, so, you will always show "Upvote", but clicking it again(in case you already upvoted it) will cause to destroy it. And clicking it again will Upvote it. Got it, I didn't see it that way in the beginning. Have you tried changing `form_for course.votes.build` to `form_for [course, Vote.find_by(user: current_user)]` ?, just for the first `if`

Comment: @fanta sorry, that doesn't work either